# Storing an array of references to arrays

Tags: c#

I want to create an array of references to my arrays. The reason for this is because i want to optimise my fast Fourier transform algorithm to be branchless - or rather, less branchy.

The idea behind it is i have two arrays:

`Array1` and `Array2`

I need to ping pong between the two in a for loop so i want to store the reference to the arrays like this:

```
[0] = Array1Ref
[1] = Array2Ref
[2] = Array1Ref
. . .
```

Is it possible to do this in C#? If so how would you define such an array - would i need to use unsafe ?

Comment: Why not just do a swap of the two array variables at the end of the loop?

Comment: Because that involves using if statements such as `if(i%2 == 0) arr1 : arr2`

I am trying to see if i can make it faster by aligning the for loop iteration with an array of references. This is a micro optimisation attempt.

Comment: Are the 2 arrays of the same type?

Comment: @TheGeneral yes they are same type and length.

Comment: `var someArray = new WhatEverTypeItIs[][];` which is an array of array of WhatEverTypeItIs

Comment: No, that does not involve branches. Just do an unconditional swap. And re-assign the variables.

Comment: An unconditional swap ? How would you do that exactly without a branch ? My current branch is: `arr = arr == arr1 ? arr2 : arr1;`

Comment: `temp = arr1; arr1 = arr2; arr2 = temp;` More performant than what you have in mind.

Comment: @NicoSchertler oh - okay thats much simpler ! Thanks ! :) Saves on memory too!

Comment: @WDUK: Since C#7, you can even write `(arr1,arr2) = (arr2,arr1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access a different array in each iteration of the for loop without using a conditional, you can keep swapping two variables and use one of them.

```
var arrayRef = Array1;
var theOtherArrayRef = Array2;
for (...) {
    // use arrayRef in places where you would have accessed the array of array references
    
    ...

    // C# 7 tuple syntax
    (arrayRef, theOtherArrayRef) = (theOtherArrayRef, arrayRef);

    // pre-C# 7:
    /*
    var temp = arrayRef;
    arrayRef = theOtherArrayRef;
    theOtherArrayRef = arrayRef;
    */
}
```

Comment: Does the C#7 tuple compile to the same code or different ?

Comment: @WDUK My simple investigation on sharplab.io showed that they compile to different IL, but are JIT'ed to the same ASM code.

Comment: @WDUK Wait, no, if I use arrays the IL is the same as well. (I used ints at first).